# Why does a function called inside a inline function not require definition?

Tags: c++, inline, one-definition-rule

Consider the following example:

```cpp
extern void not_defined();

void f() {
    not_defined();
}

int main() {}
```

If I were to compile and link the above program, I get a linker error `undefined reference to not_defined()`. (https://godbolt.org/z/jPzscK7ja)

This is expected because I am ODR using `not_defined`.

However, if I make `f()` a inline function, the program compiles and links correctly (https://godbolt.org/z/qEEob9ann):

```cpp
extern void not_defined();

// inline is added here
inline void f() {
    not_defined();
}

int main() {}
```

This also works for inline definitions of member functions (since they are also inline?) (https://godbolt.org/z/xce3neofW):

```cpp
extern void not_defined();

struct C {
    void f_member() { 
        not_defined(); 
    }
    
    void recurse() { 
        f_member(); 
    };
};

inline void f_free_inline() {
    not_defined();
}

// void f_free() {
//     not_defined();
// }

int main() {
    C c;
    // f_free_inline();
}
```

If I were to uncomment `f_free` or `f_free_inline()` in `main()` it no longer works . This effects seem to be even transitive, since `recurse` calls `f_member`, and `f_member` calls `not_defined()`.

So my questions is, what's special about inline functions that makes this possible?

**EDIT:**

This trick cease to work if the inline function is inside the purview of a module (even if it is not exported):

```cpp
export module mod_interface;

extern void not_defined();

export inline void f_module() {
  not_defined();
}
```

The above would result in a linker error for `not_defined`.

This is sad because I am porting a library to modules and suddenly got a lot of undefined references. Some of those functions in it were wrapped inside inline functions.

Comment: You do not call `f()`, thus no its body inlined, and there's no `not_defined()` calls.

Comment: I suspect there is no "there" there for inlined functions unless they are actually *used*. I don't have time to peel into the standard to cite reference that allows this. Sooner or later I suspect someone will, however.

Comment: One of the unique properties of an ODR violation is that "no diagnostic is required".

Comment: In both cases, you're not *calling* the inlined function, so not ODR-using it.   Since you have a function that is called by the inlined function, but not ODR-using it anywhere else, your function is not ODR-used.    Add a call of your inline function somewhere (or otherwise ODR-use it) in a source file where its definition is visible, and you'll find the linker will complain about your non-inline function not being defined.

Comment: @273K Yes, but if `f_free_inline` is not inline, this no longer works. So what's special about the inline keyword?

Comment: Incorrect conclusion. A definition is required. "[basic.def.odr] A function is odr-used if it is named by a potentially-evaluated expression or conversion." Therefore `not_defined()` is odr-used by `f()` both in its non-inline and inline forms. "Every program shall contain at least one definition of every function or variable that is odr-used." A violation of a "shall" makes your program ill-formed. However the clause ends with "no diagnostic required", which means that the compiler is not required to tell you that you failed to satisfy a requirement. It can just do whatever it wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard is not only a set requirements for compiler behaviour. It's also a set of requirements to programmer's behaviour.

GCC's linker wouldn't complain if a function `X()` that ODR-used a missing symbol `Y` is `inline` or `static` function, as there is no possibility that they would be called from outside module if it has local linkage and negligible, if it was inline.

But lo! Disregard the fact that you're able to compile and run this program, your program is ill-formed according to standard. Only in case of inline function `X()` linker would optimize it out as soon as it didn't found a reference to inline `X()` in any of compile units.

If it's not inline function, it would stay until final stage of linking and the missing name will be looked up through modules. Implementation of your compiler is such that it would be searched for before excluding unused `X()`. Some other compiler may behave differently.

That's why it's "ill-formed" code, but "no diagnostic required". Diagnostic is possible with certain implementations. Some implementations will diagnose both cases as an error and some are unable to detect your deception. Some implementations will detect the problem only if you had more than one compile unit.